# R Shiny problem to pass reactive input to another function after plotting

Tags: r, shiny

I am new user of R Shiny and I have got a problem with passing reactive input to another function after plotting this reactive input.
In short, I want to create application which allow user to upload csv file, then choose x and y variables, plot these variables and then calculate area under curve of this plot. I could do everything except the last point. Plotting is fine, so I could pass reactive input to `ggplot`, but I could not pass it further to AUC function. Code line 126-129, at the end of coding. I know it is something very stupid which is missing, but now I am really stack. Tried different things, different wrong messages. Now it is: argument 1 is not a vector. I could run AUC is will make hard input of variables names such as `AUC(data()$time`, `data()$response`, method `="spline")`, but I could not pass into AUC function user input for some reason.

Sorry for the stupid question.
Thank you for the help.

Here is the whole code.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)
library(pROC)

library(shinythemes)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Column Plot"),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Upload File",
                 titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),


                     tags$br(),
                     checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                     radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                  c(Comma=',',
                                    Semicolon=';',
                                    Tab='\t'),
                                  ';'),
                     radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                  c(None='',
                                    'Double Quote'='"',
                                    'Single Quote'="'"),
                                  '"')

                 ),



                 mainPanel(
                     tableOutput('contents')
                 )
             )
    ),
    tabPanel("Plot",
             pageWithSidebar(
                 headerPanel('My Plot'),
                 sidebarPanel(

                     # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                     selectInput("xcol", "X Variable", ""),
                     selectInput("ycol", "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                     plotOutput("MyPlot")
                 )
             ),


             ######     
             h4("Area under curve"),
             textOutput("AUC")

    )



    )
)
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    # added "session" because updateSelectInput requires it


data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1) ## ?req #  require that the input is available

    inFile <- input$file1 


    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)


    # Update inputs (you could create an observer with both updateSel...)


    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))


    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
                     choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])

    return(df)
})

output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()
})

output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- req(input$xcol)
    y <- req(input$ycol)




    p <- ggplot(data(), aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color="blue", size =7)

    plot(p) 


    ############
    # Here is the problem, I can not pass x and y to the AUC function to calculate area under curve
    # for the user input

    output$AUC <- renderText({

        AUC <- AUC(data()$x, data()$y, method ="spline")
    })
 #######################   

})









})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call the columns `x` and `y` in your function `AOC` but these columns are only defined in your `renderPlot`, not in the whole server.

Replacing `x` and `y` by `input$xcol` and `input$ycol` (and using `[[ ]]`) allows to compute the area under the curve.

Corrected example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)
library(pROC)

library(shinythemes)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),


                 tags$br(),
                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ';'),
                 radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                              c(None='',
                                'Double Quote'='"',
                                'Single Quote'="'"),
                              '"')

               ),



               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents')
               )
             )
    ),
    tabPanel("Plot",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('My Plot'),
               sidebarPanel(

                 # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                 selectInput("xcol", "X Variable", ""),
                 selectInput("ycol", "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("MyPlot")
               )
             ),


             ######     
             h4("Area under curve"),
             textOutput("AUC")

    )



  )
)
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # added "session" because updateSelectInput requires it


  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1) ## ?req #  require that the input is available

    inFile <- input$file1 


    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)


    # Update inputs (you could create an observer with both updateSel...)


    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))


    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])

    return(df)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- req(input$xcol)
    y <- req(input$ycol)




    p <- ggplot(data(), aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color="blue", size =7)

    plot(p) 


    ############
    # Here is the problem, I can not pass x and y to the AUC function to calculate area under curve
    # for the user input

    output$AUC <- renderText({

      AUC(data()[[input$xcol]], data()[[input$ycol]], method ="spline")
    })
    #######################   

  })









})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:** you may have an error

> Error: maximum number of subdivisions reached

but I suppose this is due to the function `AOC`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now tried with [[ ]] around the input as you suggested and it works smoothly!